# DateTimePicker not working

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on MVC project, and I've been trying to integrate (jquery) [datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) so far if I add it as a simple HTML control it works as expected:

_layout.cshtm

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

View
     >

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
</script>
```

But when I try to used embeded on my code it don't work:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deliveryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.deliveryDate, new { @id = "datetimepicker", @type="text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.deliveryDate)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestion?

Please let me know if you need more code, I would gladly to share it.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you included `jquery.js` as well as the datepicker? Saying 'it doesn't work' is never enough information for someone to help you.

Comment: Do you have multiple items you're trying to set to `datetimepicker`? That'll probably break, because `id` should be unique.  Try using a `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: try to call it without {} and see if jquery is included

Comment: Check in your console if you have some errors and update the post (my recomendation is use the chrome console, has better logs)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had a similar problem before and the problem is the `{ @id = "datetimepicker", @type="text" }` the reference: `jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});` it's ok,  but you need replace the `type=text` for `type="datatime"` that should works

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deliveryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.deliveryDate, new { @id = "datetimepicker", @type="datetime" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.deliveryDate)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This makes no sense. You do not need to set `@type="datetime"` for jquery datepicker. OP appears not to have included `jquery-ui.js` (only `jquery.js`) which means that this code will render the browsers implementation of the HTML5 datepicker (which has limited support), not the jquery datepicker

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think he's forcing this property to use a `type="text"` when the view is generated, and the jquery picker by default works with `type="text"`

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor()` generate `type="text"` so adding `new { @type="text" }` is pointless (its ignored by the helper so it make no difference at all). Changing it to `@type="datetime"` means it will render the browsers HTML5 datetimepicker becaue OP has not included the relevant script, which from the link in the question is `<script src="/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>` You have given OP an alternative (which only works in some browsers and not at all in FireFox), not the answer to the question

Comment: @StephenMuecke well, if that is not the answer, why works? lol. Tested in all the browsers ;)

Comment: @MrMins, Have a look at the [XDSoft DateTimePiker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) that OP is referring to, then right click on one of the date pickers and inspect the element. They are all `<input type="text" ...>`. (which OP already has) and they require the `jquery.datetimepicker.js` file (which OP does not have). I assume your confused between the HTML5 datetimepicker and the jquery datetimepicker OP is referring to.

Comment: You're not rigth, its working con IE, firefox and chrome and its not the default HTML5 datepicker, because it showing time picker as well. JquerryUI is being loaded on BundleConfig. But as per XDSoft jqueryUI is not required.

Comment: If OP has not included the `jquery.datetimepicker.js` file by XDSoft (nothing to do with `jquery-ui`), how could it possibly render the XDSoft datetimepicker? And the XDSoft datetimepicker does not require `@type="datetime"` as there own examples show. If this solution is working for OP then its because its rendereing the HTML5 datetime picker, not the one by XDSoft. And `jquery-ui` is not being loaded anyway - the bundle only includes `jquery-{version}.js`

Comment: As per the [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/xm95xx/8), it is NOT the default Chrome Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datetimepicker is an extension of jQuery which comes with jQuery UI. As far as I can tell, and as pointed out by Stephen Muecke, it doesn't seem like you are including any jQuery UI code. Here is a link to the jQuery UI download page to get the minimum code required to get the datepicker to work: http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.2&themeParams=none&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000000

Comment: I got jquery and jqueryUI using nutget from visual studio 2013. I got all scripts and CSS files on my project.